# After submitting the form nothing is happening

Tags: php, email

This is my code and I want "form-handler.php" code so that anyone submitting the form their details should come to my email address code is:

```
<!-- CONTACT FORM-->
<div class="wt-box">
    <form class="contact-form cons-contact-form" method="post" action="form-handler.php">
        <div class="contact-one p-a40 p-r150">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="username" type="text" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="message" rows="3" class="form-control " required="" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="site-button black radius-no text-uppercase">
                            <span class="font-12 letter-spacing-5">Submit</span>
                    </button>
```

Comment: try `<input type="submit"> ` instead of button. and where is your form?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Where is your PHP code? The only code provided is HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, which is *"a little bit different from other sites"*; please [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [how to ask an On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **In short:** if you try writing the form handler we'll help - but we won't write it for you.

Comment: Your question title seems to express surprise that “nothing is happening”, but then it sounds like you did not even have any code for this yet, and want us to provide it for you? Please note that this is not how this site works, we don’t write code for you - you need to do the ground work; we can help you if you have _specific_ issues with it. Please go read [ask].

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Where is the PHP for this and the rest of the form?

Answer (score -2):

follows an example of how you can do this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>

<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

You need the tag `<form>` and try use `<input>` instead `<button>`

> Font: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail

:)

Comment: You missed the part of the question about sending email

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: `<br><br>` — CSS has been around since 1996. We don't need to hack margins using line breaks.

Comment: `<h2>HTML Forms</h2>` - Why a subheading without a heading?

Comment: Your HTML has errors that would be picked up by a [validator](https://validator.nu/)

Comment: `<form action="/action_page.php">` — For the purpose specified in the question, a GET request isn't really suitable. It should be a POST request.

Comment: "try use `<input>` instead `<button>`" — Don't. Unless you are trying to support ancient versions of Internet Explorer which don't properly support `<button>`, you should use the `<button>` element. It is much more flexible.

Comment: re edit: `action="mailto:someone@example.com"` — Support for this is *awful*. It is impractical to use outside of an Intranet where the browsers and email clients users have is strictly controlled. (And in that environment it is still easier to just set up a server which can send mail server side).

Comment: To summarise: don't copy/paste some ancient, shonky nonsense from w3schools and expect a positive response... sorry ;)

Comment: @Quentin this is just an example of a form. Do you have a better answer to help? Post her.

Comment: @EdiCarlos — It's a **bad** example of a form. I'm not going to write a better answer for the reasons CD001 explained in a comment on the question.